# How do I update variable from Flask Form to a continuously running python script, without the script stopping and waiting for the user form input?

Tags: python, forms, variables, flask

This code does not work, but It's a basic start. I need some direction on how to have a script running, and when user wants to change variables through a web from, to have the new variables passed into the script, without the script stopping and waiting for the information?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import render_template
import time

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def my_form():
    return render_template("form1.html")

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def my_form_post():
    text = request.form['text']
    myFunction(text)    
    return text

def myFuction(var):#loop does not stop and wait for form submission...
    while True:
        print var
        time.sleep(0.25)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a surprisingly complicated question to answer completely in this format because the best solution really depends on what you're trying to do, how much data you have, and how long it needs to last.

plain Flask really doesn't intend for you to be running scripts continuously on the server side. The idea is that Flask is not doing anything until it gets a request. When a request is received, Flask only runs functions needed to handle the request, optionally send a reply, and optionally kick off a callback. It then stops everything until the next request.

Also when you deploy this to a production server, it's likely going to be behind some parallelizing web server software so that it's possible to handle requests from more than one place at once. That basically calls a new process every time a request comes in which prevents you from using shared/stored variables. It means you're not going to be able to keep track of variables between requests even if you could run a script indefinitely in the background.

There are various modules that let you work get around this. Flask-SocketIO for example lets you layer a socket connection over flask routs so you can pass data back and forth to JS in the browser. Or Flask-Session can add server side session extensions that allows you to keep server side session variables between requests. Another option likely better option depending on your use case would be to have user requests store things to a lightweight database, and then have your continuously running script be a completely separate program which also gets information out of the DB. Again, it all depends on what you're trying to do.

Sorry I can't be more prescriptive, but I hope it helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you. Your last suggestion seems like a good one. Basically I'm having a Python program checking soil moisture at certain times of the day. But I want the user to be able to adjust these times of day, submit, and have the script continue onward. The database need only be very simple! Could I write a .csv file upon Flask form request with new variable value, then, the main script can call upon that file to update itself, independently? And if so, how do I run both simultaneously on a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: yea, you could absolutely do it with csv if you wanted. All the details of implementing it on a Raspberry Pi would be thousands of words though. The Pi is basically just a regular Linux machine. A webserver should run as a background service.  then just run the main script. Shouldn't have trouble running both. If you're going to use a CSV file, make sure your scripts don't hold the file open too long, and build in error handling so that they can try again or fail gracefully if the other program is using the file. A proper DB can do that scheduling for you though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing not the best approach to the give task. As per @TheAtomicOption answer it's definitely a lot of ways to solve that. 
You asked for direction and I'm running a lot of home automation on my own. The main idea is to keep your website separate from other services.

Consider separating some functionality and using MQTT broker. (*MQTT is a simple and lightweight publish/subscribe protocol, you can easy find more information on web*).

**Example structure:**

```
1. WebServer(Flask app) - to retrieve devices data and configure parameters
2. MQTT broker - more info on web
3. MQTT client - subscribed to all topics and writes all the data to the DB
4. Devices publishing and subscribed to predefined topics.
```

Another part is am MQTT client running in the loop (written on python using paho library). The purpose of this client is to receive ALL the traffic and depending on the topic name - perform specific action.

**Example:** received '24.5' on the topic '/garden/sensor5/moisture'-->write info into DB(I sue MySQL along with SQLAlchemy).

Last part of this approach is the webserver, which you can run on the same local machine or on external server. To change the periodicity of the sample from any sensors I', changing it in the input on the website, click 'Save' and click on 'Save' button will call JS ajax POST request to the function in the Flask application. I store new parameters to the database and using flask-mqtt publish new parameters to the chosen device topic. All the devices subscribed to the MQTT topics and after receiving any information, performed programmed actions.

**Example:** Device subscribed to '/garden/sensor5/moisture' and receives JSON data {'interval':'20', 'alertThreshold':'50'} --> interval 20sec and if moisture level>50% send an alert.

Please feel free to ask any question.
Best regards,
Oleg Somov